# Assigning multiple rows to a single row of different table SQL

Tags: c#, sql, system, inventory

Is it possible to assign several rows to a single row of a different table? Doing purchase order I have a table for Suppliers then under that I have items that are in the different table. Giving me headache for over a week now...

Comment: We might need a little more information here - by which I mean, more code! Based on what you said, I am going to suggest reading up on many-to-one relationships. That's where you need to start learning, until then save on posting "questions" that have no attempt within them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you really want, but my first guess us that you have a many-to-many situation. Am I correct?

If my assumption is correct, the default solution is creating a junction-table. If for instance an Order can contain many Products, and a Product can be associated with many Orders, you usually create something like an OrderDetail table. And that would look something like this:

```
OrderDetail:
- OrderId
- ProductId
- Quantity
```

If you wish, you can even force that the combination of OrderId and ProductId should be unique with a unique key contraint (or unique index, which is usually the same).

Comment: Well what i really want is to make a purchase order that contain products and supplier details and all can be called in a single purchase order no.

Comment: You cal look at the structure of the w3schools database (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/ and select 'try it yourself'). That database looks perhaps similar to what you try to achieve. For instance, each product-record contains the id of the supplier (referring to the supplier-id in the supplier-table). And with a Select-statement that includes a few joins, you can retrieve all the information about a single purchase order (if you filter on an order number in the where-clause). You will however retrieve multiple records, with each record having the same purchase order number.

Comment: Thankyou ! much appreciated